# Why isn't my domain pointing to my heroku rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I ran `heroku domains:add www.samstil.es` and `heroku domains:add samstil.es`, and my CNAME aliases area of my domain registrar looks like this: [registrar http://puu.sh/4Kpib.png](http://puu.sh/4Kpib.png)

Shouldn't I be able to go to http://samstil.es/ right now, and have it show my rails welcome page?

Answer (score -1):

I walked this same path just yesterday and the only way I found to fix this was using the IP number instead of the `app.herokuapp.com` path. I just triggered a `ping samstil-es.herokuapp.com` from my terminal and used that IP.

Give it a try, hope that helps, worked for me in name.com.

Comment: You really shouldn't use the IP address - they may/will change. The best way to solve this is to use a DNS provider that supports ALIAS records like DNSSimple or Amazon Route53 - this allows you to use an apex domain like samstile.es and have it correctly set to samstil-es.herokuapp.com at the DNS level. Read more about apex domains at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain